# Angular2 RC5: where should I put interface in NgModule?

Tags: angular

I am upgrading from RC4 to RC5, I have a shared module for my services, pipes and interfaces. Where should I include the interface file in my shared module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interface is not an **Injectable** Angular 2 class (service / component / pipe - none of them), so you do not have to put it in shared module. If you want to use an interface - just import proper file.